# Is it possible to find \$h\$-parameters for single transistor?

Tags: bjt

When I read \$h\$-parameter topic, there was a definition that; the four constants which describe the behavior of two port transistor network are called hybrid parameters.

So my question is: Can \$h\$-parameters be found only for two port system or can we find it for single transistor also?

Comment: A note: the usage of $h$ parameters, which emerge from a black box treatment of the transistor, should be avoided in the design of transistor circuits (and, in fact, these parameters are no longer specified by manufacturers).

Answer (score 5):

> Can h-parameters be found only for two port system or can we find it for single transistor also?

When we specify h-parameters for a transistor, we are talking about making a two port that contains only a single transistor (i.e. we *are* finding the h-parameters for a two-port).

Therefore, the h-parameters depend how you are connecting the transistor to form the two-port.

The usual quoted \$h_{fe}\$ is determined assuming we are connecting the device in the *common emitter* circuit.

The word *common* is crucial. The reason we call this circuit a **common** emitter circuit is because the emitter is common to the two ports:

[image]

Now you can see the two ports are formed by the base and emitter nodes on the input side and by the collector and emitter nodes on the output side.

Comment: Ca u plz explain in detail

Comment: I think he has explained it well. It gives you enough information to continue your research and answers your question. If you don't understand one particular aspect then explain where you are having difficulty rather than asking him to "explain in detail".

Comment: @s, I edited to make it more clear why this answers the question you asked.